# How to loop the files in a directory, and set variables named after the files?

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, variables, for-loop

I have a project that needs to loop through files in a directory, and set variables named after the files that contain the data of the files.

For example:

I have folder `/tmp` with files `data_1.dat` and `data_2.dat`.

**data_1.dat**:

```
E-123
```

**data_2.dat**:

```
B-321
```

When script runs, it makes two variables: `data_1.dat`, which value is `E-123`, and `data_2.dat`. which value is `B-321`.

I have tried this, but I don't know what I am missing:

```
for filename in os.listdir():
    filename = open(filename, 'r').read()
```

Comment: How will the rest of your program know what variable names to use? Besides, `data_1.dat` and `data_2.dat` aren't legal Python variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Creating new variables at runtime is almost never a good idea. For instance, how will you know what variable names to write after the looping is done?

Instead, use a dictionary with the filenames as the keys.

```
files = {}
for filename in os.listdir():
  file_contents = open(filename, 'r').read()
  files[filename] = file_contents
```

Then, you can loop through the filenames with `files.keys()`.

> If for some reason you really need to create new variables, you can use the globals or locals dict depending on whether or not you are in a function.

```
for filename in os.listdir():
  file_contents = open(filename, 'r').read()
  globals()[filename] = file_contents
```

Comment: Better hope there's no file named `__builtins__` in the current working directory.

Comment: What are you quoting in the two `> ` block-quotes?  If that's someone else's writing, you should [cite them properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: I was using it to highlight key points of the answer. Is there something better for that?

Comment: I use either `#` section headers, `_`italics`_`, or `**`bold`**`, depending on the situation.  See the [mardown docs](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more.

Answer (score 2):

When you're faced with a problem where you want the name of a variable to be determined at run time (e.g. based on input strings), what you really want is a key-value mapping data structure. In Python, the right way to do this is with a dictionary.

```
file_data = dict()
for filename in os.listdir():
    file_data[filename] = open(filename, 'r').read()
```

Now, you'll be able to look up the contents of each file in the `file_data` dictionary by name (`file_data["my_file.txt"]`), and loop over the dictionary using a construct like

```
for filename, contents in file_data.items():
     print filename, len(contents)
```

Comment: Thanks! Not exactly what i needed, but it works anyway!